# Is the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^4$ path connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers, connectedness, path-connected

I am asked whether the unit sphere
$$X=\{(x,y,z,w)|x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1 \}\subset \mathbb{R}^4,$$
is path connected or not.

I just know that $X$ is a closed subset. How can I answer this question?

Is there any hint? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an idea of what this set looks like?

Comment: It is not a discrete set. What do the analogous subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$ look like? Can you draw them?

Comment: @Servaes it is exactly s^3!and it is path connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $X$ is the unit sphere in $\Bbb{R}^4$. Any two distinct $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^4$ are contained in some plane $Y\subset\Bbb{R}^4$, and hence $x,y\in X\cap Y$. But $X\cap Y$ is then a circle in $Y$, which is of course path connected. So $x$ and $y$ are connected by a path in $X\cap Y\subset X$, hence $X$ is path connected.

Comment: thanks!that's true.but is there any method for such problems?for example how about $\{(x,y,z)| x^2 + y^2 − z^2 = 1\}\subset R^3$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any general methods. Subsets of Euclidean space in general can be very nasty... But drawing pictures often helps.

Comment: ok.thanks.do u have any idea for this special case i mentioned?

Comment: I would also suggest drawing a picture, and considering lower-dimensional slices. Consider asking a new question if you want a more elaborate answer.

Comment: *In this case, slices with constant $z$-value are circles and slices with constant $x$- or $y$-values are hyperbolas. Every point is on such a circle, and every pair of circles is joined by a hyperbola, so every pair of points is joined by a path.